# Lookup aggregation in mongoDB using groovy in Jmeter

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I have two collections in MongoDB. I am using JSR223 sampler in Jmeter to perform lookup operation on mongoDB.
**Database name:** DB
**Collections names:** c_1, c_2

Groovy code to perform lookup aggregation in MongoDB.

```
c_1.insert(new BasicDBObject(["id" : 1, "name" : "abc", "lastName" : "kumar",  "companyId": 10]))  

c_2.insert(new BasicDBObject(["id" : 10, "companyName" : "Microsoft", "numEmployee" : 100 ]))  

// build the $lookup operations  
DBObject lookupFields = new BasicDBObject("from", "c_2");  
lookupFields.put("localField", "companyId");  
lookupFields.put("foreignField", "id");  
lookupFields.put("as", "companydoc");   
DBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject("$lookup", lookupFields);  

// build the $project operations  
DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("name", 1);  
projectFields.put("lastName", 1);  
projectFields.put("companyId", 1);  
projectFields.put("companyName", "$c_2.companyName");         
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields);  
List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(lookup, project);  
AggregationOutput output = c_1.aggregate(pipeline);  
for (DBObject result : output.results())    
{  
    System.out.println(result);  
}
```

**Error:** Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: lookup for class: Script79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not compatible with [Groovy GStrings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html), as per [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/):

> If you need to escape the $ or ${} placeholders in a GString so they appear as is without interpolation, you just need to use a \ backslash character to escape the dollar sign:
>
> ```
> assert '${name}' == "\${name}"
> ```

so either go for single quotes like:

```
DBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject('$lookup', lookupFields);
```

or escape the dollar sign with the backslash:

```
DBObject lookup = new BasicDBObject("\$lookup", lookupFields);
```

the same approach for `$project`, `$c_2.companyName`, etc.

More information: [How to Load Test MongoDB with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks. But List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(lookup, project); AggregationOutput output = c_1.aggregate(pipeline); It throws error-java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments.